# How can I call a server side method when browser gets closed

Tags: 2010, jquery, asp.net, visual-web-part

I have created a SharePoint 2010 visual web part. I have create a method `CheckPref` in `usercontrol.ascx.cs`. How can i call this method when the browser window is closed? If i use`ScriptManager PageMethods`, an error "PageMethods is undefined" is thrown.

```
function HandleClose() {
           PageMethods.CheckPref();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can check.

- Is the `ScriptManager` set with [`EnablePageMethods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods(v=vs.110).aspx)?
- Did you create a `static` method in your c# code behind with `[WebMethod]` attribute?

You can refer these discussions to check more:

- [asp.net ScriptManager PageMethods is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16775117/1047998)
- [ASP.net PageMethods return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19580633/1047998)
- [Execute server side code on close of a browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/89661/Execute-server-side-code-on-close-of-a-browser)

Comment: Yes, ScriptManager's EnablePageMethods is true and the method i am calling is static and public.

Comment: @ThomasMathew: Can you edit your question to include C# code snippet? It might help others with solibving your issue.